# Error in javascript button - Unexpected Token else

Tags: javascript, custom-button, ajax-toolkit

I have written simple logic to through javascript alert if the description field on account object has some value I am displaying alert and if it null displaying different alert. But the below code throws error "Unexpected Token Else"

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")} 

var testField='{!Account.Description}';
var checking=sforce.connection.query("select Description from account where id='001p000000AgZk7' limit 1 ");
var recs = checking.getArray("records");
for(var i=0;i<recs.length;i++){
if(recs.length < 0)
alert('empty');
}
else{
alert('filled');
}
```

Comment: You have not closed the For loop, always look for JavaScript errors in dev tools.

Comment: even though i closed facing same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirement, you do not need to query the description attribute.

You can get the description from merge field and better to compare with that value.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")} 

var testField="{!Account.Description}";

if(testField !=null && testField.trim().length>0)
{
    alert('filled');
}
else
{
    alert('empty');
}
```

It has been assumed the custom button is on record detail page.

Answer (score 4):

You missed the opening bracket around your if statement:

```
for (...) {
    if (...)
         //  ^ open bracket missing
    }
    else {
    }
```

That means the `if` block is simply the next statement, and your closing bracket after it terminates the for loop, making your code approximately:

```
for (...) {
}
else {
}
```

Which is obviously not valid syntax.

Syntax aside, your actual conditional is impossible to fulfill. The `length` of an `array` will *never* be less than zero. It is either empty (`length=0`), or populated (`length>0`). The value is strictly non-negative.

Comment: for(var i=0;i<recs.length;i++){ 
if(recs.length < 0){ 
alert('empty'); 
} 
} 
else{ 
alert('filled'); 
} done but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I believe you do not require the for loop at all, because you are fetching only one record (using limit 1). So below code should work fine:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")} 

var testField='{!Account.Description}';
var checking=sforce.connection.query("select Description from account where id='001p000000AgZk7' limit 1 ");
var recs = checking.getArray("records");

if(recs.length > 0)
  alert('filled');
else
  alert('empty');
```